# Additivity of Fisher information

Tags: self-study, fisher-information

Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition) states that "the information in a random sample of n independent and identically distributed observations is n times the information in a sample of size 1". I know that formally it's proven via linearity of expectation but I am looking for an intuitive explanation.

On the other hand, I found at https://ani.stat.fsu.edu/~debdeep/Fisher.pdf that in the case of iid random variables $I_X(\theta)=\sum^n_{i=1}I_{X_i}(\theta)$.

I am confused and it would much appreciated if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Why are you confused? For the iid case, the two results you cite are identical

Answer (score 1):

The additivity really follows from assuming independence and indentical distributions (i.i.d.)and linearity of the derivative operator and of expectations. If $L_i(\theta| x_i)$ is the likelihood of the $i$th observation, independence allows us to form the likelihood of all observations as the product of each observation, $L(\theta| x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^nL_i(\theta| x_i)$ and taking logarithms turns products into sums,

$log\left(\prod_{i=1}^nL_i(\theta| x_i)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^nlog(L_i(\theta| x_i))$. Then the first or second derivative will be linear in the terms inside the sum. Secondly, the Expectation operator is also linear so taking an expectation of the second derivative terms will also (still) add.

If you prefer geometric intuitions, you can consider i.i.d. assumption as assuming orthogonality of each dimension, where each dimension is an observation.